# What is the best way to set an environment variable in .bashrc?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

When setting up a variable in `.bashrc`, should I use this?

```
export VAR=value
```

Or would this be enough?

```
VAR=value
```

What is exactly the difference (if there is one)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## The best way

```
export VAR=value
```

## The difference

Doing

```
VAR=value
```

only sets the variable for the duration of the script (`.bashrc` in this case). Child processes (if any) of the script won't have VAR defined, and once the script exits `VAR` is gone.

```
export VAR=value
```

explicitly adds `VAR` to the list of variables that are passed to child processes. Want to try it? Open a shell, do

```
PS1="foo > "
bash --norc
```

The new shell gets the default prompt. If instead you do something like

```
export PS1="foo > "
bash --norc
```

the new shell gets the prompt you just set.

**Update:** as Ian Kelling notes below variables set in `.bashrc` persist in the shell that sourced `.bashrc`. More generally whenever the shell sources a script (using the `source scriptname` command) variables set in the script persist for the life of the shell.

Comment: "only sets the variable for the duration of the script (.bashrc in this case)"

That is false/misleading. Variables set in this way persist into the interactive shell that read .bashrc.

Comment: `PS1` is a bad example of a variable to be exported as an environment variable. It's only meaningful to child processes that are shells and it's interpreted differently by different shells (e.g., bash and dash). Best practice is to simply set it as a regular shell variable in the `.bashrc`. Better examples of environment variables include `HOME`, `PATH`, `EDITOR`, etc.

Answer (score 11):

Both seem to work just fine, but using export will ensure the variable is available to subshells and other programs. To test this out try this.

Add these two lines to your .bashrc file

```
TESTVAR="no export"
export MYTESTVAR="with export"
```

Then open a new shell.

Running `echo $TESTVAR` and `echo $MYTESTVAR` will show the contents of each variable. Now inside that same shell remove those two lines from your .bashrc file and run `bash` to start a subshell.

Running `echo $TESTVAR` will have an empty output, but running `echo $MYTESTVAR` will display "with export"